# Python versions advice

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

Throughout the years I have installed different versions of Python rather cluelessly, and now I find myself stuck with how to go about managing them. I have an M1 MacBook Pro.

I am not the best around terminal, packages, configuration files etc, and I would just appreciate some advice on how to clean everything up. Some of this stuff I find quite confusing.

So here are some of the command line outputs that hopefully will show a full picture of my configuration:

```
janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.9.8
```

```
janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*   
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janek  admin  83  3 Jan 13:52 /usr/local/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script -> ../Cellar/python-argcomplete/3.2.1/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  73 20 Dec 18:05 /usr/local/bin/python3.11 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  80 20 Dec 18:05 /usr/local/bin/python3.11-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  81 20 Dec 18:05 /usr/local/bin/python3.11-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  71  9 Jul  2021 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  78  9 Jul  2021 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
```

```
janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janek  admin  38 14 Nov  2021 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janek  admin  45 14 Nov  2021 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janek  admin  40 14 Nov  2021 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janek  admin  47 14 Nov  2021 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/bin/python3.9-config
```

So it seems to me that I am using the homebrew Python version. However when I list brew Python versions I get this:

```
janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % brew list python python3
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python

janek@Janeks-MBP-3 ~ % brew list | grep python        
python-argcomplete
python-packaging
```

Now this is confusing to me and I would like to understand what's happening.

Other information that might be helpful is that inside my `.zprofile` I have:

```bash
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

and inside `.zshrc`:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

So to **summarise** I am looking to understand and clean up what's happening here. It would be great to uninstall what I have and start fresh with some Python version management i.e. pyenv. That said there are many posts online about being careful when deleting Python; hence my question here. Maybe it's best to uninstall brew here too. If anything I should at least want to use Python 3.11 as my default one, as I have struggled setting that up as well.

Comment: Just to note, you don't need a "clean start" to use `pyenv`. It installs Pythons in (yet another) separate location, and part of its job is to update your `PATH` so that the desired Python is found automatically via path lookup.

Comment: Right thanks, but I would still like to get rid of some of these versions if possible

Answer (score 0):

Once you install python using `brew install python`, you will see the following message after installation :

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin

You need to add the symlink to your path so that the python/python3 commands are linked to the brew installation. You can do this by using :

```bash
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

You should add this line to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file so the correct PATH is loaded every time.

Comment: Modifications to `PATH` belongs in `.zprofile` or `.bash_profile`.